# MySQL: Ensure consecutiveness of numbers in a column

Tags: mysql, numbers, contiguous

I need some help for a MySQL query.

Let's assume we have a table with the columns "id", "unique_id" and "consecutive_id". The numbers in column "id" are NOT always consecutive, while we have to keep consecutiveness in column "consecutive_id". Basically every row should get its own consecutive number, but sometimes there may occur rows that should share the same consecutive number. Such rows have the same value in column "unique_id". I need a query to find the first ID of a row that has more than one row with the same consecutive ID and a unique ID which is not part of another row.

In created a little fiddle at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hy8SACLyM2D65H2ZY31c2f/0 to demonstrate my issue. As you can see, IDs 3 and 5 have the same consecutive number (2). That's okay as they share the same unique ID. IDs 9, 10, 12 and 14 also have the same consecutive number (4), but only IDs 9 and 10 have an identical unique ID. Therefore in this case the query should find ID 12.

Can you please help me with developing a solution for this?

Thank you so very much for your help in advance.

All the best,

Marianne

Comment: What if there are 4 rows with the same consecutive numbers, and 2 of them have the same unique ID and the other two also have the same unique ID (but different from the first two)? Which of them should be considered "wrong" and returned by the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT unique_id)` to find the values of `consecutive_id` that have different `unique_id`.

```
SELECT consecutive_id
FROM test 
GROUP BY consecutive_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT unique_id) > 1
```

You can then join this with your original table, group by both `unique_id` and `consecutive_id`, and get the rows that just have a count of `1`, which means they're not equal to the rest of the group.

Since there can be multiple outliers, you need another level of subquery that just gets the minimum outlier for each consecutive ID.

```
SELECT consecutive_id, MIN(id) as id
FROM (
    SELECT a.consecutive_id, MIN(id) AS id
    FROM test AS a
    JOIN (
        SELECT consecutive_id
        FROM test 
        GROUP BY consecutive_id 
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT unique_id) > 1) AS b
    ON a.consecutive_id = b.consecutive_id
    GROUP BY a.consecutive_id, a.unique_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS x
GROUP BY consecutive_id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/umH3wWHWR5uqxjULPE4Ecd/0)

Comment: Barmar, that works like a charm! Thank you so very, very much for your great solution and have a nice day! Marianne